# Balls in an urn - Transition matrix

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, transition-matrix

There are 2 colorless balls in an urn. In a sequence of events, a ball is randomly chosen and painted in red or black, then we put it back in the urn. We do it again, if the ball is painted, we put replace it whit a different color (if we pick a red ball, we put a black one in the urn). If the ball is not painted, we randomly paint it in red or black.

How can we describe the transition matrix of this process with states $(x,y,z)$, where $x$ is the number of colorless balls, $y$ is the number of red balls and $z$ is the number of black balls.

My first attempt was to study the case when we only have one ball, I get this matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

When I go for the second case, the 2 balls, things get a little confused. I know i can have the following cases: $(2,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,2,0),(0,0,2)$.

Attention: I posted a similar question earlier, but now I think it is better written. I've tried to write a similar matrix but i failed. I've even thinked and managed to do an 6x6 matrix, using the possible combinations, but did not maneged to do an 3x3. Any help is appreciated. If i wrote something that isn't clear, please let me know!

Comment: As was pointed out to you before, since you know there are $6$ states, your transition matrix must be $6\times 6$.  Just sort out the probabilities of passing between each of your states.  The $(i,j)^{th}$ entry is the probability of passing from state $i$ to state $j$.

Comment: Hey! Well, are you sure about the $6 \times  6$? There is no way to write it in an $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Why don't you get states with more than $2$ balls? If the state is $\ (1,1,0)\ $ and you pick out the red ball, then according to your instructions "we put it together with a different color" (i.e together with a black ball), so why doesn't the state transition to $\ (1,1,1)\ $?

Comment: I edited the post. We only have 2 balls all the time. I'm sorry, It was badly written.

Comment: Because their are six *distinct* states to transition between, then by definition the transition matrix shall be $6\times 6$ .

Answer (score 0):

With states $(u,r,b)$ with $u$ colorless, $r$ red and $b$ black balls
and $u+r+b=2$ we have  6 states (= the number of weak compositions of 2 into 3 parts),
that can be ordered in the standard lexicographic way as
$(2,0,0)$,
$(1,1,0)$,
$(1,0,1)$,
$(0,2,0)$,
$(0,1,1)$,
$(0,0,2)$.
The transition matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
200\\
110\\
101\\
020\\
011\\
002
\end{array}
\right)'
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0   & 0   & 0   & 0 & 0   &0\\
1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0 & 0   &0\\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0 & 0   &0\\
0   & 1/4 & 0   & 0 & 0   &0\\
0   & 0   & 0   & 0 & 1/2 &0\\
0   & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1 & 0   &1\\
0   & 0   & 1/4 & 0 & 1/2 &0
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
200\\
110\\
101\\
020\\
011\\
002
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
The first column describes that 2 colorless balls end up with one colorless and a red or black.
The 2nd column describes that a colorless and a red ball end up with 2 red or (1 red and 1 black) or (1 colorless and 1 black) etc.